# How to do linebreaks in a pdf table with fpdf generated from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I found this code in an older post. It works absolutely fine for my project except one problem. If the string from the mysql db is too long it will overflow the cells. I want it to automatically break and start a new line in the particular cell.

Original post I got the code from: [Basic table creation fpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704962/basic-table-creation-fpdf)

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class People {
    public function all() {
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=UTF-8', 'user', 'password');
            $query = $db->prepare("SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, age, email FROM people ");
            $query->execute();
            $people = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            //echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage();
            $result = false;
        }
        $query = null;
        $db = null;
        return $people;        
    }
}

class PeoplePDF extends FPDF {
    // Create basic table
    public function CreateTable($header, $data)
    {
        // Header
        $this->SetFillColor(0);
        $this->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->SetFont('','B');
        foreach ($header as $col) {
            //Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
            $this->Cell($col[1], 10, $col[0], 1, 0, 'L', true);
        }
        $this->Ln();
        // Data
        $this->SetFillColor(255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('');
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($row as $field) {
                $this->Cell($header[$i][1], 6, $field, 1, 0, 'L', true);
                $i++;
            }
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
}

// Column headings
$header = array(
             array('First Name',  30), 
             array('Middle Name', 30), 
             array('Last Name',   30),
             array('Age',         12),
             array('Email',       47)
          );
// Get data
$people = new People();
$data = $people->all();

$pdf = new PeoplePDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->CreateTable($header,$data);
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: use `$pdf->WordWrap($text,int_width);`

Comment: Doesn't work or rather I don't know how to define the method.